# Axios/mongodb request, PromiseState stuck on pending, then() part is not called

Tags: mongodb, promise, axios

I'm trying to update my mongodb database in javascript by accessing some documents from the database, changing a specific document and then performing a patch request via axios.

When I get to the patch request I'm able to update the database however the promise is stuck on pending and thus, the then() part of the code is not run.

This is the main structure of the code:
In the first part the documents are requested from the database via axios.get:

```
function updateDocument(someinputdata){
    g = axios.all([axios.get('/getData1),axios.get('/getData2)])
    .then(response => {
        Data1 = response[0].data;
        Data2 = response[1].data;
        adjustData(Data1,Data2);
    });
}
```

In the second part a specific document is changed and a patch request is called:

```
function adjustData(Data1,Data2){
    ...getting specific document and change value from specific field...
    var newRec = {
        title: "dummyTitle",
        rate: newRateValue
    };
    
    promise = axios({
        url: '/patch/The Real Title',
        method: 'PATCH',
        data: newRec,
        headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" }
    })
    .then(() => {
        console.log('I want this text to display but it doesn't')
    });
}
```

If I console.log(promise):

```
Promise {<pending>}
    __proto__: Promise
    [[PromiseState]]: "pending"
    [[PromiseResult]]: undefined
```

On the server side I have this:

```
router.patch('/patch/:title', (req,res) => {
    const updatedPost = Model.updateOne(
        { "title": req.params.title},
        { $set: { "rate" : req.body.rate}},
        (err, result) => {
            if(err) {
                console.log(err);
                throw err;
            }
        })
        .then(
            console.log('This text is displayed');
       )
})
```

I want to use the first then() part to update some HTML
Why is the patch request stuck on pending (so not fulfilled or rejected)?

Comment: First of all, don't forget the `catch` method to catch and handle any errors during the request and secondly, your server-side code isn't sending any response back to the client.

Comment: Thank you for your response! I had just figured it out before I saw your post ;)

Answer (score 1):

I've figured out what my problem was.
I needed to add

```
res.json({msg: "Your data has been saved"});
```

to the code on the server side.